# WP 8.1 XAML app crushes time to time on the Windows 10 Mobile at MapControl

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

We started testing of our Windows Phone 8.1 Xaml app at windows 10 when it was delivered to our test phone, especially Lumia 640XL and Lumia 930.

And we got a problem the app closing unexpectedly in any time and in any place. No any scenario to reproduce it.

Managed debugger reports "ExecutionEngineException" without any details and any stack.

Native debugger reports Access violation, please investigate a call stack below.

Please help me to find a way to find a cause of crush!

P.S. The app working perfectly on the windows phone 8.1

coreclr.dll!ComCallWrapper::GetComIPFromCCW(class ComCallWrapper *,struct _GUID const &,class MethodTable *,enum GetComIPFromCCW::flags)    Unknown
    coreclr.dll!Unknown_QueryInterface_Internal(class ComCallWrapper *,struct IUnknown *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
    coreclr.dll!Unknown_QueryInterface(struct IUnknown *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bdd84b0()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.dll!6335a582() Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.dll!6332aa3c() Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.dll!6335168a() Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.dll!633523f8() Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.dll!63359e60() Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd202c2()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bece3a4()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd09ff8()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd09f16()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd0d000()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd0cbb6()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd0cab8()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd0c8d4()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd0c836()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd0c7ba()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bd7ef74()  Unknown
    MinUser.dll!7740b816()  Unknown
    MinUser.dll!774082b0()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.dll!6df2f0ea()   Unknown
    Windows.UI.dll!6df2ef72()   Unknown
    Windows.UI.dll!6df2eeca()   Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bf0501a()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bf04fdc()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!6bf04e9c()  Unknown
    twinapi.appcore.dll!75eb352a()  Unknown
    twinapi.appcore.dll!75eaef88()  Unknown
    SHCore.dll!763643a2()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77a154ba()    Unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a cause of the app crash. It happens if GC tries to release a map control which contains a custom XAML control in a children collection.

So to fix it you must remove all children from the map at map's unload event.

Comment: Your comment saved me from long time debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue just appeared for our App, after upgrading to the last Insider build (10.0.14295.1000). The map control crashes on Windows 10 Mobile, but before that, Visual Studio requires a missing file from the OS: "uielement.cpp". It also gives the known location: "d:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp".

Does anyone know where is this missing file? Maybe we are missing some new part of the SDK?

After the file is not found, a exception is thrown:

> Unhandled exception at 0x633FB4B1 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in ***.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

From what I know location 0x00000000 is NULL.

The "Output Window":

> Exception thrown at 0x7799D247 in ***.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: web::http::http_exception at memory location 0x0426F3C8.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7799D247 in ***.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7799D247 in ***.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: web::http::http_exception at memory location 0x0426F3C8.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7799D247 in ***.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: web::http::http_exception at memory location 0x06D8F9D0.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x633FB4B1 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in ***.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

The "Source Search" details:

> Locating source for 'd:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp'. Checksum: MD5 {7 d7 a1 1e 56 b b 82 cf a4 b6 bd 97 32 30 bd}
>   The file 'd:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp' does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'd:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp'...
>   Looking in the Edit-and-Continue directory 'C:***\enc_temp_folder\'...
>   The file with the matching checksum was not found in the Edit-and-Continue directory.
>   Looking in the projects for 'd:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vc7\atlmfc'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vc7\crt'...
>   Looking in directory 'c:\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfcm'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.10240.0\ucrt'...
>   Looking in directory ''...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfcm'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\abi'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\mincore'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\minwin'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\wrl'...
>   The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: d:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file 'd:\rs1\onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp'.

Note: The App works on previous builds of Windows 10 Mobile and it still works on Windows 8.1.